# Swift extension for all subclasses of a class

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to write an **extension** for all classes inherited from **class A**
using some code like that:

```
extension T where T: A { 
    override func someMethod() {}
}
```

**EDIT:**

My specific need is to override a method of some class A (which is a class not a protocol!) in its subclasses and do the same implementation in all the subclasses (without define another class **B** that is inherited from class **A** and then inherit from **B**)
I thought **extension** is a good way to do that using Generic type **T** specifying that **T** is inherited from **A** but swift do not allow that. Is there some way to do that?

**Another Edit**

Class **A** is a built-in class has **someMethod()** which is also a built-in method

Comment: What is your specific need?

Comment: Edit your question with proper desc of your problem .but  What you need is protocol !!

Comment: I think my question is well-explained!

Comment: @MohanadRefaai no it's not. Describe your specific need.

Comment: Any way I edited it @RobertDresler.

Comment: @MohanadRefaai  Simply Not possible In any programming lang.  how you can override something without subclassing it (it is murder of oops concept) ?.

Comment: Why don't you just use this superclass `A`? This is the whole concept of classes and subclasses.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya No. I subclassed it. I just want to write an extension for all the subclasses in one time.

Comment: @RobertDresler because this class A is a built-in class.

Comment: Then you can Write ext of Super Class it can be accessible from all subclasses Like Your class A is super class then write extension for it.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya the desired method to be overridden is also a built-in method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you ***cannot*** override methods in the superclass HumanMother in a generic way... yet.. which I personally find to be quite annoying. Class hierarchies and extensions don't work as well together in swift as this cool example may lead-on to be.

If you want to define a method (not an override) for all subclasses, this will work:

First define a protocol:

```
protocol BigMamma {
   func damnGirl()
}
```

Then define it for subclasses of "HumanMother" types.

```
extension BigMamma where Self: HumanMother {
   func damnGirl() {
      print("Yeah Boi")
   }
}
```

Ref: https://www.vadimbulavin.com/multiple-inheritance-swift/

Comment: Yes, the answer is that. There is no way to implement such a scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and the comments, I suggest you do following:

1. create a subclass of the "built in class"
2. override needed methods in this subclass
3. create subclasses from your overridden subclass
4. use overridden method

When you subclass and overwrite a specific method like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // do stuff
}
```

Then all what is implemented in this method is also used by the subclasses. If you now override this method again in a subclass of this class, then `super.viewDidLoad()` will call the overridden code of your subclass.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I mentioned that in my question (without defining another class B that is inherited from class A and then inherit from B) because I do not want to change my classes hierarchy. But you are right I think this is the only way!

Comment: There is nothing wrong having a `BaseClass` for common used functionality. Glad that it helped!